# OpenCV webcam not showing

Tags: python, opencv

I want to make a program that show my live webcam using OpenCV, and whenever I press SPACE it will take a picture.

I am using python 3.6.4 and OpenCV 4.1.1. It is for a program, that with the help of tensorflow, it will take a picture, and will recognize if someone from a database is in there or not. This is my current code:

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
img_counter = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if not cam.isOpened():
        raise IOError("Cannot use webcam")
    elif cam.isOpened():
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if not ret:
        break
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        #ESC pressed
        break
    elif cv2.waitKey(1) == 32:
        #SPACE pressed
        img_name = 'students_{}.png'.format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print(img_name + 'was captured')
        img_counter += 1
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when I run it, it raises this error:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

My goal right now is to make it show the webcam, take a picture, and save it in the project's folders.

Does anyone know what is wrong?
Or does tensorflow has a feature like that that I don't have to use openCV?
Thx a lot, Gabi

Comment: check `print(frame)` - probably it will show `None` which means it couldn't get image from camera.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: value `0` in `VideoCapture(0)` usually means built-in camera in notebook. If you use external camera then you may have to use use different value or you may have to use path to camare - ie. on LInux it can be `/dev/video0`, `/dev/video1` , etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer: I use an external camera via a usb, so I had to change cv2.VideoCapture(0) to cv2.VideoCapture(1)
I'm not sure if there is a way to do this directly through tensorflow, but I am trying to figure it out.